# How to invoke server side code from Ribbon

Tags: development, ribbon, custom-action, postback

I want to create a Button in my Ribbon which modifies some fields in my items.. In details I want to select more than one element and select my "link" button and make the elements be "linked" by an integer field populated with the same value.

I already have other ribbon custom button but for those it was easy to work only with Javascript. Can anybody suggest me how to do this thing?

I read online someone suggest to create a custom WebControl invoked by "postback" to react to event... There is any other way or a good tutorial?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [__doPostback](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/) method on the client:

```
__doPostback('myPostBack','');
```

Then, on server you should have something like this:

```
const string myPostBackId = "myPostBack";

public override CreateChildControls()
{
    // ...

    if (this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == myPostbackId)
    {
        string textBoxValue = this.Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        // do whatever you need with textBoxValue
    }

    // ...
}
```

Also, I have two working examples for my [Fluent Ribbon API](http://spribbon.codeplex.com) opensource project, of how to work with postbacks. I think, exploring these examples could help, even if you don't intend to use Fluent Ribbon API. Here they are:

1. [Simple example](http://markeev.com/sharepoint/ribbon/?topic=html/postBack.htm) from the project documentation site
2. Article, which explains [how to use Ribbon ToggleButton in conjunction with UpdatePanel to create multiview pages](http://markeev.com/Articles/sharepoint-ribbon-togglebutton.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could also create an application page which you pass the GUIDs of the selected items via a JavaScript redirect. currentsite/_layouts/AppPage?GUIDS=guid1,guid2&ReturnURL=/Pages/currentpage.

Have your code complete the request then redirect to the list view via the ReturnUrl paramater.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it:

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using javascript submit. Example:

```
var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('/SharePointRibbonDemo/RibbonDemo.aspx?ids=' + itemIds + '&listId=' + listId);
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", pageUrl);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using javascript `_dopostback`. Example:

```
function RibbonDemo() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
    __doPostBack('RibbonDemo', itemIds + ";" + listId);    
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed));
}

function Success() {
    var theForm = document.forms[0];
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = "";
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = "";
}

function Failed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function RibbonDemoEnable() {   
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    return SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context).length >= 1;
}
```

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using SharePoint Page dialog. Exaple:

```
function RibbonDemo() {
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
    var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(
        '/SharePointRibbonDemo/RibbonDemo.aspx?ids=' + itemIds + '&listId=' + listId);
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 500;
    options.height = 300;
    options.url = pageUrl;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, OnDialogClose);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }

 function OnDialogClose(result, target) {
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        alert('OK was clicked");
  }
 }
```

See this for more information: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/07/invoke-server-side-code-on-sharepoint.html

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also we  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. Please fix this and flag for a moderator to review. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apart the suggestion wrote from Andrey and Anders I suggest to you another solution. By javascript call a wcf to do the work do you need.