# How to insert selected items after Ribbon Click

Tags: ribbon, postback

I have a code (following http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.it/2010/01/new-one.html).

I have a custom WebControl which receives a postback and react with server side code. Thanks to Javascript I can read with this code the elements:

```
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var myItems = '';
    var i;
    for (i in items) {
        myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
    }
    insertParam('IDs', myItems);
    return handleCommand(commandId, properties, sequence);
```

I have in a variable all the selected items...

Now I need to pass this parameters to my "Server Side Script" as params... So I tried this way:

```
function insertParam(key, value) {
key = escape(key); value = escape(value);

var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

var i = kvp.length;
var x; 
while (i--) {
    x = kvp[i].split('=');

    if (x[0] == key) {
        x[1] = value;
        kvp[i] = x.join('=');
        break;
    }
}

if (i < 0) { kvp[kvp.length] = [key, value].join('='); }
document.location.search = kvp.join('&');
```

}

This function executed locally works but on my server doesn't work. How could I pass this simple string to my Postback method??

Even if I wrote down something like:

```
document.location = 'www.google.it';
```

Doesn't redirect! So... How can I do? Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform postbacks from ribbon controls, there are at least two options:

1. Use [SPRibbonPostBackCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spribbonpostbackcommand.aspx) in conjunction with implementing [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) interface for your control (server-side both)
2. Use `__doPostBack` in JS, and then Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] server-side

Let me explain both approaches in detail.

#### 1. SPRibbonPostBackCommand approach

The post you presented above hints the first approach, however it doesn't provide clear example of how to implement it.

I'd recommend another post on the same topic, which is a bit more apprehensible:

- http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2009/10/creating-a-custom-ribbon-tab-in-sharepoint-2010/ (see section "Additional Ribbon Commands")

In brief, first you should add `SPRibbonPostBackCommand` object to commands collection which is passed to `SPRibbonScriptManager.Register*` functions. Then, you should implement `IPostBackEventHandler` and SPRibbonPostbackCommand.DeserializePostBackEvent function to get id and arguments of the command.

#### 2. __doPostBack approach

The other approach could be a bit more easier to understand, but a bit more hardcore at the same time. Use `__doPostBack` JS function, and then add basic code on server, which analyses `Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]`. Parameters for the postback could be passed by serializing/deserializing data through `Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]`.

I've already posted links and examples for this approach under one of your previous questions:

- [How to invoke server side code from Ribbon](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37174/how-to-invoke-server-side-code-from-ribbon)

Comment: Thank you! I've already deploy something working, my problem is how to pass parameters to the server side code.. Can you help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Problem solved... Don't know HOW but now URL Rewriting works!